# How to pass boolean value (returned by a function) to boto3 put_item() function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a function,

```
def _get_package_(sandboxId):

    for i in response_tci_sandboxes['Items']:
            if sandboxId == i['id']['S']:
                    if i.get('sandboxType') == 'operational':
                            return True  ## Please note that true(lowercase) is not allowed
                    else:
                            return False

    return 1
```

Now the problem is when I am passing the value returned by above function to put_item function, It is throwing error, because it expects boolean value to be in lowercase i.e. true or false.

I tried to use it something like this.

```
 str(_get_package_(sandboxId)).lower
```

But put_item is putting it as an string and request is denied because the datatype is BOOL.

Comment: can you include your put_item function ?

Comment: I am using `aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://vagrant_apps.json `.  (where vagrant_apps.json is the file with all the items including the item with the value returned by above function) getting following error.
Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
But when i am just editing the returned value and putting it as `false` instead of `False`. It is working